# What is the best way to make a blue-purple rainbow that returns the current color in java?

Tags: java, colors

In java, you can make a rainbow function like this:

```
float hue = (System.currentTimeMillis() % 6000) / 6000f;
return Color.HSBtoRGB(hue, 0.4f, 1);
```

However, this only returns a rainbow of all colors possible.

How would I make this blue and purple, instead of all of the colors?
By this I mean, constantly switching between different shades of blue and purple, and returning whatever the current value is on function call, using a similar system.

Edit: I forgot to mention this, but I want to make the transition smooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with your HSB system of generating the color, then you need to restrict the hue.  Right now you are allowing any possible hue.

The [HSB system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) (or HSV) defines the hue system in degrees, with 0 or 360 being red, 120 being green, and 240 blue.  So you want something between 240 and 300 degrees.

The [Color.HSBtoRGB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Color.html#HSBtoRGB(float,float,float)) method normalizes a float value ranging from 0.0 to 1.0 to a range of 360 by multiplying your argument by 360.

> The hue component can be any floating-point number. The floor of this number is subtracted from it to create a fraction between 0 and 1. This fractional number is then multiplied by 360 to produce the hue angle in the HSB color model.

To create the necessary range you start with blue at 240 and multiply your random value by 60 to tweak the range so it's between 240 and 300.

```
float hue = (System.currentTimeMillis() % 6000) / 6000f;

// Restrict to between blue (240) and purple (300).
hue = (240.0f + 60.0f*hue) / 360.0f;

return Color.HSBtoRGB(hue, 0.4f, 1);
```

Comment: This is what I needed, however the change from purple to blue is extremely sudden. Is there a way I could make a smoother transition?

Comment: You could keep track of your previous `hue` value.  Then, narrow the range of your random hue generation to be plus/minus 10 (or 5) from your previous hue value, ensuring that it still falls within the range of [240, 300] to keep it between blue and purple.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Purple is a combination of blue and red. So you can generate colors with the fixed blue component = 1.0 and red component = random number from 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: How would I do this using the HSBtoRGB function?